# chartjs - multi axis line chart - cannot read property 'min' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, chart.js

When running the below code **without** the `scales` and `yAxisID` values, it renders a 2 line chart with both lines on the same axis.

**UPDATE:** When only removing the `yAxisID` values from the code it runs as before without errors - although still with only a single y axis.

When adding these elements in order to get a split axis, it returns the js error `cannot read property 'min' of undefined` and the canvas is blank.

Not sure if his should make a difference, but `data` is a json object returned through an ajax request by way of a vue.js method.

Here is an example of how the data.sales variable looks in the browser console:

> sales: (187) [0, 0, 43.2874, 10.276, ..., 23.834]

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart_canvas").getContext('2d')

    var basic_line = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: data.labels,
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Price',
          yAxisID: 'B',
          fill: false,
          borderColor: ["#668cff"],
          data: data.price
        }, {
          label: 'Sales',
          yAxisID: 'A',
          fill: false,
          borderColor: ["grey"],
          data: data.sales
        }],
        options: {
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              id: 'A',
              position: 'left',
              type: 'linear' 
            }, {
              id: 'B',
              position: 'right',
              type: 'linear'
            }]
          },
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: false
        }
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is merely occurring due to the  fact that, you have placed the `options` object/property, inside the `data` property, while it should be outside.

Here is the revised version of your code :

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart_canvas").getContext('2d')

var basic_line = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: data.labels,
      datasets: [{
         label: 'Price',
         yAxisID: 'B',
         fill: false,
         borderColor: ["#668cff"],
         data: data.price
      }, {
         label: 'Sales',
         yAxisID: 'A',
         fill: false,
         borderColor: ["grey"],
         data: data.sales
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            id: 'A',
            position: 'left',
            type: 'linear'
         }, {
            id: 'B',
            position: 'right',
            type: 'linear'
         }]
      },
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false
   }
});
```